# How to sort files according to date created with google apps script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I'm looking to sort the files in a folder by the date they were created or last modified. I'm loading the contents of a folder in google drive with the following code:

```
var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderID);
var contents = folder.getFiles();
data = file.getId();
var image = DriveApp.getFileById(data);
```

My understanding is that `contents` above is an array containing a list of file IDs in the drive. Is it possible to sort `contents` by date created/modified before proceeding to the next step?

Comment: contents is not an array it's a fileIterator.  It might be possible to convert to any array with Array.from().  Check your favorite javascript reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
### Sorting an array of files by datecreated
function myfunction() {
    var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderID);
    var contents = folder.getFiles();
    let arr = [];
    while (contents.hasNext()) {
        let file = contents.next();
        arr.push(file)
    }
    //sort arr by dateCreated
    arr.sort((a, b) => {
        let vA = new Date(a.getDateCreated()).valueOf();
        let vB = new Date(b.getDateCreated()).valueOf();
        return vA-vB
    });
    //the rest of your code makes no sense. 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, from what I understand, is this code assigning the file names to an array based on the creation date? If so, is there a quick way I can look at its contents?

Comment: What is the contents?

Comment: `contents` contains images. My full code is:

Comment: Actually this code is simply sorting arr based upon creationDate.  What you wish to do with the sort array is up to you.  As far as displaying images I'd probably do it with a diallog.

Comment: I wanted to use the elements of the sorted array to open images but am having no luck with it. Also, am getting an error from the line `let file = contents.next();` in your code: Exception: Cannot retrieve the next object: iterator has reached the end.

Comment: Perhaps the folderId is wrong or perhaps the folder has no files in it.

Comment: The fileid is correct and it has files in it, not sure why I am getting errors as I use this command in my own code. Think I will just delete and resubmit this question as I think not initially sharing the full code caused some confusion. Thanks for your help.